# I want to get images form product gallery of a product and display them one by one in Product detail page

Tags: product, layout, product-images, catalog, gallery-image

This is the `gallery.phtml` code  which is displaying main thumbnail image only

```
    <?php
$images = $block->getGalleryImages()->getItems();
$mainImage = current(array_filter($images, function ($img) use ($block) {
    return $block->isMainImage($img);
}));

if (!empty($images) && empty($mainImage)) {
    $mainImage = $block->getGalleryImages()->getFirstItem();
}

$helper = $block->getData('imageHelper');
$mainImageData = $mainImage ?
    $mainImage->getData('medium_image_url') :
    $helper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('image');

?>

<div class="gallery-placeholder _block-content-loading" data-gallery-role="gallery-placeholder">
    <img
        alt="main product photo"
        class="gallery-placeholder__image"
        src="<?= /* @noEscape */ $mainImageData ?>"
    />
</div>

<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getMagnifier() ?>,
                "data": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
                "options": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getOptionsJson() ?>,
                "fullscreen": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getGalleryOptions()->getFSOptionsJson() ?>,
                 "breakpoints": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Any solution??????

I want other images also be displayed not only main thumbnail image

Answer (score 0):

1. create custom block file :

> app\code\Vendor\Extension\Block\Myblock.php

```
<?php 

namespace Vendor\Extension\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Myblock extends Template
{
    protected $productloader; 

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productloader)
    {
        $this->productloader = $productloader;
    }

    public function getProductAllImages($productId)
    {
       $product = $this->productloader->create()->load($id);
       return $product->getMediaGalleryImages();

    }

}
```

2. Now on your phtml do code like this one.

   ```
   $product_id = 32;
   $productimages = $block->getProductAllImages($product_id);
   foreach($productimages as $productimage)
   {
      echo "<img src = ".$productimage['url']. " height=100 width=100 />";
   }
   ```

Comment: But I don't want to set product id=32

Comment: I want it to get Product id of current product automatically

Comment: That you want to get from the registry if you on product page.

Comment: yes from registry it should get automatically

Comment: Then pass that Id and do change accordingly, so you get images for that product.

Comment: if answer help accept it as solution, so it will help other in community.

Comment: No IT DID Not work for me

Comment: which issue you are facing into this one?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'url' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: Debug that, have you pass proper product Id? and what it return to you.